# How do I troubleshoot a hang in React Native's Getting Started?

Tags: node.js, react-native, watchman

I'm using the [React Native Getting Started instructions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html). I am using a 2010 MacBook Pro with macOS Sierra 10.12.6.  The computer has Node.js v8.4.0.

I'm new to React Native, and also to React and to Node, so I might be missing something basic.  I do have React working on the same computer.  I followed the instructions on the page above, hoping to see the `npm start` command start a development server and print a QR code on the terminal, as the instructions say.

The first time I tried Getting Started, I got some error messages, which you can find below.  Based on those messages I installed watchman and tried `npm start` again.  That time, the app seemed to start a server.  I saw no QR code, but after a few seconds some error messages appeared and then nothing.

Here's what the shell session looked like.  Some parts were lengthy (hundreds of lines) and I've left them out.  I have included all errors and warnings I found.

```
bash-3.2$ create-react-native-app AwesomeProject # verbatim from the getting-started page
Creating a new React Native app in /Users/dvincent/Desktop/react-native-test/AwesomeProject.

Using package manager as npm with npm interface.
Installing packages. This might take a couple minutes.
Installing react-native-scripts...

[?25hAwesomeProject@0.1.0 /Users/dvincent/Desktop/react-native-test/AwesomeProject
`-- react-native-scripts@1.3.0 
  +-- @expo/bunyan@1.8.10 
  | +-- moment@2.18.1
```

Here I'm leaving out hundreds of lines that don't seem important.  These do seem important:

```
    +-- uuid@3.1.0  deduped
    +-- xmldom@0.1.27 
    `-- yesno@0.0.1 

npm WARN react-redux@5.0.6 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0 but none was installed.
Installing dependencies using npm...

[?25hnpm WARN deprecated connect@2.30.2: connect 2.x series is deprecated
[?25h
> fsevents@1.1.2 install /Users/dvincent/Desktop/react-native-test/AwesomeProject/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

[fsevents] Success: "/Users/dvincent/Desktop/react-native-test/AwesomeProject/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v57-darwin-x64/fse.node" already installed
Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile
[?25hAwesomeProject@0.1.0 /Users/dvincent/Desktop/react-native-test/AwesomeProject
+-- expo@20.1.1 
| +-- @expo/vector-icons@5.2.0 
| | `-- react-native-vector-icons@4.1.1 
| |   `-- yargs@6.6.0  deduped
| +-- babel-preset-expo@3.0.0 
| | +-- babel-plugin-module-resolver@2.7.1 
| | | +-- find-babel-config@1.1.0
```

Here I am omitting more lines, before reaching some warnings and seeing the Success! message as expected.

```
|   +-- y18n@3.2.1 
|   `-- yargs-parser@4.2.1 
|     `-- camelcase@3.0.0  deduped
`-- react-test-renderer@16.0.0-alpha.12 

npm WARN react-native-gesture-handler@1.0.0-alpha.17 requires a peer of react@>= 16.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-native-branch@2.0.0-beta.3 requires a peer of react@>=15.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN lottie-react-native@1.1.1 requires a peer of react@>=15.3.1 but none was installed.


Success! Created AwesomeProject at /Users/dvincent/Desktop/react-native-test/AwesomeProject
Inside that directory, you can run several commands:

  npm start
    Starts the development server so you can open your app in the Expo
    app on your phone.
```

and ending with the following.

```
We suggest that you begin by typing:

  cd AwesomeProject
  npm start

Happy hacking!
```

So I proceeded, like this:

```
bash-3.2$ cd AwesomeProject/
bash-3.2$ npm start

> AwesomeProject@0.1.0 start /Users/dvincent/Desktop/react-native-test/AwesomeProject
> react-native-scripts start

1:59:58 PM: Unable to start server
See https://git.io/v5vcn for more information, either install watchman or run the following snippet:
  sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=5242880
  sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=524288

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! AwesomeProject@0.1.0 start: `react-native-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the AwesomeProject@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/dvincent/.npm/_logs/2017-09-01T03_59_58_661Z-debug.log
```

I set aside the kernel suggestion for the time being and instead installed watchman.

```
bash-3.2$ npm install watchman
[?25hAwesomeProject@0.1.0 /Users/dvincent/Desktop/react-native-test/AwesomeProject
`-- watchman@0.1.8 
  +-- cli@1.0.1 
  | +-- exit@0.1.2 
  | `-- glob@7.1.2 
  `-- eco@1.1.0-rc-3 
    +-- coffee-script@1.12.7 
    `-- strscan@1.0.1 

npm WARN lottie-react-native@1.1.1 requires a peer of react@>=15.3.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-native-branch@2.0.0-beta.3 requires a peer of react@>=15.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-native-gesture-handler@1.0.0-alpha.17 requires a peer of react@>= 16.0.0 but none was installed.
```

Then I tried to start the server again.

```
bash-3.2$ npm start

> AwesomeProject@0.1.0 start /Users/dvincent/Desktop/react-native-test/AwesomeProject
> react-native-scripts start

2:29:06 PM: Starting packager...
***ERROR STARTING PACKAGER***
Starting React Native packager...
Scanning 767 folders for symlinks in /Users/dvincent/Desktop/react-native-test/AwesomeProject/node_modules (21ms)
Loading dependency graph.
Running packager on port 19001.


2017-09-01 14:29 node[22151] (FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-22)
***ERROR STARTING PACKAGER***

2017-09-01 14:29 node[22151] (FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-22)
***ERROR STARTING PACKAGER***

2017-09-01 14:29 node[22151] (FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-22)
```

At this point I stopped waiting
and captured the shell transcript to start on this question.  I left it going while writing this, for over 40 minutes, with no further output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a known issue when you install watchman using npm. It can be fixed by removing watchman installed using npm and installing it using homebrew.

```
# Remove any existing binaries
rm -rf /usr/local/var/run/watchman/
# Remove any npm globally installed instances
npm uninstall watchman
# Nuke the last brew installed version
brew uninstall watchman
# Brew install and build latest
brew install watchman
```

For more details see this [issue](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/64).